# changetable doesn't have current changes when in a trigger?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have the following trigger to save the changes to a log table. However, it will not catch the changes triggered the trigger? Or is there another solution?

```
alter trigger trigger_xxx on table1 after delete, update, insert
as
begin
  declare @lastVersion bigint = coalesce((select max(SYS_CHANGE_VERSION) from [log]), 0)

  insert into [log]
        ([SourceColumnDescriptionPattern], SYS_CHANGE_VERSION, SYS_CHANGE_OPERATION, SYS_CHANGE_COLUMNS, SYS_CHANGE_CONTEXT)
  SELECT [SourceColumnDescriptionPattern], SYS_CHANGE_VERSION, SYS_CHANGE_OPERATION, SYS_CHANGE_COLUMNS, SYS_CHANGE_CONTEXT
  FROM changetable(changes [table1], @lastVersion) as ct
end
```

Comment: Would you just want the inserted/deleted records for the insert into the log? What is `changetable(changes [table1], @lastVersion)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change Tracking is intended for synchronization purposes. For example you can use it to find out if a application side cache needs to be refreshed. Therefore you do not want for that information to show up before the transaction is committed. As your trigger executes within the transaction the changes are not visible yet.

Why are you trying to duplicate the information available in Change Tracking? Cant you just use those functions and DMVs instead of your own?

Assuming you have a good reason, your best bet is probably to use a trigger and capture the affected primary key together with other pertinent information like a timestamp yourself. However there is no real good way to enforce that trigger being executed before all others so you might still end up in the same situation. You could try sp_settriggerorder in your case: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186762.aspx It might be enough in your situation.

Comment: Is it good practice that I set retention period to a very long period? Or just set AUTO_CLEANUP off?

Comment: I have no experience with very large change data sets. There is a chance that there will be a performance impact, so you should do some testing. However, keeping the data for a few days should be fine. If you see a performance problem, you could transfer the data into a table in regular intervals with a SQL Agent job.

Comment: Yes, I thought of creating an agent job and kick off the job in the trigger too.

Comment: Kicking of a job is a fairly expensive operation. You'd probably be better off running the job once a minute than dealing with that overhead in every transaction.